# How to write a Large WinForms application?

Tags: winforms, design-patterns

I'm going to write a rather big/complex WinForm application such as Paint.NET, SharpDevelop, etc. I think one of the most important things to build such an application is to structure the project properly to increase maintainability and control the complexity.

So what kind of patterns or practices show I use? Any blog posts, papers, open source projects are welcomed. I'm trying to learn something from SharpDevelop but it's rather huge for me to step into.

PS: I'm an experienced programmer formerly targeting to web developement(asp.net, rails, etc.). So I know some design principles and how to use them when implement business logics. Maybe I really need now is a sample to get started with a WinForm application so that I can realize how to handle the menus, controls and others. I've learnt something about the MVP pattern but still unconfident to start a large/complex application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For big projects the methodology and the tools you are using are equally as important as the architectural design. You need to set up a source control system (like SVN) from day one. Also, it is very good to have a standard build procedure and perform builds in a daily basis. The build procedure should include running all tests, which you should also put some effort in implementing from the start.

Regarding the structure, I believe the single most important thing is to divide your project into building blocks with mimimal dependecies on each other. This way you will be able to think about one small part of the system at the same time and not have to face the full complexity of it. It will also help delegate some work to a fellow programmer, if you have this chance.

In order to get started, I recommend that you implement first something minimal as quick as possible. Then work to make it better and add functionality. This will keep you motivated as you will have something concrete to work with. It will also help you identify major design flaws and important issues early enough to correct them.

Comment: I'm an experienced programmer formerly targeting to web developement(asp.net, rails, etc.). So I know some design principles and how to use them when implement business logics. Maybe I really need now is a sample to get started with a WinForm application so that I can realize how to handle the menus, controls and others. I've learnt something about the MVP pattern but still unconfident to start a large/complex application.
Thank you all the same!

Comment: First make the decision between WinForms and WPF. WPF has a steeper learning curve, but it will give you a richer User Interface. Start coding and don't worry about MVP or MVC patterns. Try to keep the UI code separate from the business logic as much as possible and that's just it. You will never get confident unless you start doing some coding, even if it is a pet project.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good beginners guide from Microsoft itself:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx

check the [Windows track](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/dd435692.aspx) there.

After mastering basics - and since you are an experienced developer - you can check this book ["patterns & practices Application Architecture Guide 2.0](http://apparchguide.codeplex.com/)" from Microsoft also.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that many of the techniques that make for successful web projects will translate to Winforms projects. Start small and grow the application incrementally. Try to keep the entire application building/working while you add features one at a time.